# Selendroid program not connecting with Appium, can't do automated testing

Tags: java, netbeans, appium, selendroid

I have used Selendroid to write a JAVA program to automate testing in android app, but there is an error coming constantly, I have included selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar,  java-client-5.0.4.jar. java-client-5.0.4-sources.jar, java-client-5.0.4-javadoc.jar files in library, still the error is occuring. Please Help, in great need.

Error :
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1}
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'Kapil-PC', ip: '192.168.43.212', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:403)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementById(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:70)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementById(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementById(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:345)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at inventorytest.InventoryTest.main(InventoryTest.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:358)
    ... 13 more
C:\Users\Kapil\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds)`

And Code :

```
package inventorytest;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
public class InventoryTest {

 private static AndroidDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, 
InterruptedException 
{

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "hih");

capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "My New Phone");

capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");


capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");


capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.kapil.inventory");              

capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".add_new_item");

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 driver.findElement(By.id("editText5")).sendKeys("Hello");

Thread.sleep(10000);
 driver.quit();


            }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how Appium contributors write [Selendroid tests](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory_tests/SelendroidModeTest.java):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.SELENDROID_PORT, SELENDROID_PORT);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.SELENDROID);
driver = new AndroidDriver<>(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

Check element searching strategies and make sure you use the right one.